# Weird boolean conversion (?)

Tags: c++

Explain pleasy why second expression returns false

```
   cout << (4==4) << endl; //1
   cout << (4==4==4) << endl; // 0
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`(4==4==4)` is basically `((4==4)==4)` which is `(true == 4)` which is `(1==4)` <sup>1</sup> which is `false` <sup>2</sup> which is getting printed as `0`.

Note that `==` has associativity [left-to-right](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), but that doesn't matter (in *this* case) because even if it had associativity right-to-left, the result would have been the same.

---

<sup>1. Due to integral promotion.</sup> 
<sup>2. Note that one might tempted to think `4` in `(true==4)` could be treated as `true` (after all `4` is non-zero, hence `true`). This thinking might conclude `(true==4)` is `(true==true)` which is `true`. But that is not how it works. It is the bool which gets promoted to int, instead of int to bool.</sup>

Comment: How can i compare 3 elements then?

Comment: @OrangeFox: `if ((x == 4) && (y == 4))`

Comment: it's called `promotion` for a reason; you unify to the more general type

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth: Yes. :-)

Comment: @MooingDuck: How about avoiding recursion, and using iteration instead? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6d9d3cca1c0839d ... only that it uses array; can we avoid that, reducing the stack usage and copies?

Comment: .. we can take array of pointers to avoid copies! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6589c6d6191643b6

Comment: @Nawaz: (A) technically it's not "recursion" so it's trivially inlined, and (B) your version can't compare `std::string` and `const char*`.  If you wanted to get really crafty you could try something with `std::tie` and the indecies trick though...

Comment: `std::tie`.. umm, I don't think that would work here. We're not comparing one set of elements with another set of elements?

Comment: @Nawaz: `std::tie` gives you a tuple of references. That plus the indecies trick, plus `std::get` lets you "iterate" over a parameter pack with an index, and iterating with an index also lets you access the subsequent item in the pack.  It's a _lot_ of work for almost no gain though.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Iterating over std::tuple using std::get, would be recursion, same as yours (the compiler might inline that though). So yes, it is no gain. Your approach is so far good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54745/discussion-between-mooing-duck-and-nawaz).

Answer (score 2):

`4==4` evaluates to `true`, which for the purpose of comparing it with `4` is converted to `1`. `1 == 4` is `false`, which is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not apply binary compare operators to more than two operants, reasonably (unless you have an overwrite making it possible, somehow).

To compare an unknown number of arguments:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename A, typename B>
bool equal(const A& a, const B& b) {
    return a == b;
}

template <typename A, typename B, typename ... Other>
bool equal(const A& a, const B& b, const Other& ... other) {
    return a == b && equal(b, other ...);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << equal(1, 1, 1) << '\n';
    std::cout << equal(1, 2, 3) << '\n';
}
```

C++ 11

Comment: ewww; don't impose *copyable* here; take by const ref; all you need is *equality_comparable*