# Multiple OR or AND conditions in IF statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, operators, logical-operators

I am having a basic doubt regarding IF statement.
Let's say I want to match string SUN with a character array(size 3).

```
if(arr[0]!='S' || arr[1]!='U' || arr[2]!='N')

cout << "no";

else

cout<< "yes";
```

Are all conditions checked in If statement or does it return true on first mismatch?

If all conditions are checked, will the the order of checking be from right to left?

Comment: Are you using c or c++?

Comment: Note that it's not really a c-style string (no null termination)

Comment: This is C++ not C. Edited the post to fix this.

Comment: C and C++ don't "evaluate" any particular direction, they [short circuit](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) in cases like this.

Comment: this is c++, the conditions will all be checked until the first one fails the condition, and then it will fall out.  (I.E. it short circuits on the first evaluation that will fall out)

Comment: @CodaFi They do evaluate in one given, particular direction, left-to-right. And there is a sequence point in between every evaluation. The compiler may stop further evaluation of the || as soon as it has encountered an operand which evaluates to true.

Comment: A chain of `||` and `&&` is evaluated left-to-right. If the result can be confirmed before reaching the end of the expression chain, the computation is terminated early.

Comment: @Lundin Perhaps I should clarify: "Evaluate" has strong implications, at least to me, of interpreted languages.  Binaries are not "evaluated" at runtime.  And what you've just described is what I just linked to.

Comment: You should check this article, it is pretty awesome explained ;) http://stackoverflow.com/q/23940505/2003898

Comment: @CodaFi Evaluation in this context, refers to order of evaluation (of operands to a certain operator), which is a formal term in the C and C++ standards.

Comment: @Lundin Let's hope so, 'cause that code's looking a little suspect.  I can edit and repost the comment if you'd like.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard

> 1 **The && operator groups left-to-right**. The operands are both
>   contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). The result is true if both
>   operands are true and false otherwise. Unlike &, && guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation: **the second operand is not evaluated if the
>   first operand is false.**

and

> 1 **The || operator groups left-to-right**. The operands are both
>   contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). It returns true if either
>   of its operands is true, and false otherwise. Unlike |, || guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; moreover, **the second operand is not
>   evaluated if the first operand evaluates to true.**

Answer (score 1):

It returns "true" on the first mismatch. Operators in both C and C++ "short-circuit". That is, an OR operator will not evaluate its right side when its left side returned true. The AND operator will not evaluate its right side if its left side returned false.

Answer (score 0):

The if-statement you wrote execute `cout << "no";` if AT LEAST one of the conditions is satisfied.

In this case, if your input is "GUN", the program checks if:

- 'G' != 'S' -> YES
- 'U' != 'U' -> NO
- 'N' != 'N' -> NO

As the first condition is satisfied, the program will execute `cout << "no";`.

If the if-statement was:

```
if(arr[0]!='S' && arr[1]!='U' && arr[2]!='N')
  cout << "no";
else
  cout<< "yes";
```

To execute `cout << "no";` ALL the conditions had to be satisfied.

For "GUN" it would be like:

- 'G' != 'S' -> YES
- 'U' != 'U' -> NO
- 'N' != 'N' -> NO

As there are two NO, the program would execute `cout<< "yes";`.

So:

- || requires just one condition to be satisfied
- && requires ALL conditions to be satisfied